# How to use Type of inheriting class as parameter

Tags: c#, typescript

I have a base class (can also be an interface) and n-classes that extend the base class.
I want to have a function that excepts only classes of the base class type.

Currently I am doing something like this

```
abstract class BaseClass{
  public abstract void Execute();
}

class MyClass : BaseClass {
  public void Execute(){
    //my code
  }
}

[...]

MyFunction(Type param)
{
  //check if param is type of BaseClass. If not, throw exception 
}
```

The problem with this implementation is, that I can pass any type of class. My goal is to prevent this.

Like in TypeScript you can do this

```
myFunction(param: {new (): BaseClass}){
   //my code
}
```

Is there a similar approach I can use in C#?

Comment: What does _“function that excepts only classes of the base class type”_ mean? Do you need to pass as a parameter a `Type` instance? A reference of a `BaseClass` type? What _actual problem_ are you trying to solve?

Comment: It doesn't seem to make sense. Since the base class is abstract, you're never going to pass something that is just an instance of that class, not a derived one. And if in fact you're working with a `Type` and can only work with one type, why is it even being passed as a parameter?

Comment: The method I am calling creates one or more objects of the given type ```param``` and calls methods of the created objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of things you can do, depending on what you **actually** want to do in the function.
Stating your actual use case makes it easier to come up with a solution.

Looking at the typescript code it looks like you want to be able to call the constructor inside the function to produce an instance of the given type that derives from `BaseClass`.

In this case I'd try using generics:

```cs
public void MyFunction<T>() where T: BaseClass, new()
{
  T myClass = new T();
  //Do stuff...
}
```

This works with interfaces/classes. It will only accept types deriving from `BaseClass`.

Answer (score -2):

Edit: updated my answer after being notified how my previous answer wouldn't know if it was a grandchild of the base class

```
public abstract class BaseClass
{
    public abstract void Test();
}

public class DerivedFromBase : BaseClass
{
    public override void Test(){}
}

public class Grandchild : DerivedFromBase 
{
}

public class Main
{
    Grandchild aClass= new Grandchild(); // Instantiate Normally

    UseIfOnlyTypeOfBaseClass(aClass);// Use Method with check like this
}

private void UseIfOnlyTypeOfBaseClass<T>(T param)
{
    if (typeof(T).IsSubclassOf(typeof(BaseClass)))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Match");
    }
}
```

Comment: This would fail if `mainClass` is a grandchild of `BaseClass`, and probably isn't what the OP wants to do anyway.

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Thanks, I wasn't aware of that, I've updated my answer to show what I think the OP is wanting